# Extra spacing for TD in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Below is mycode. Problem is whenever i use float element whose width is more than td:ed(1). It takes extra space. I appreciate your suggestion.

```
<table style="background:#ff0;border:1px solid #ccc; width:100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td  style="width:30px; border-right:1px solid #ccc; overflow:hidden">1</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Below are screen shots of .

**Mozilla** 
[image]

**IE7**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found answer for this.
For IE i added css property

table
{
table-layout:fixed;
}

This solves my problem.

Thanks.